# Elegant way of checking if 3 columns of a table are empty or set

Tags: php, if-statement

I need to write a function which checks if a 3 columns of a table are empty or set. My code works but I think it's not very elegant. Because if you want to check 4 columns, you have to rewrite the whole code. Can you rewrite this code in an elegant way?

```
                //row[0] == id 
                //row[1] == licensekey 
                //row[2] == url_1 
                //row[3] == url_2 
                //row[4] == url_3

            if($row[2] == '' && $row[3] == '' && $row[4] == ''){
                echo 'Every row is empty';
            }
            if($row[2] == '' && $row[3] == '' && $row[4] != ''){
                echo 'Row 1 and 2 are empty';
            }
            if($row[2] == '' && $row[3] != '' && $row[4] != ''){
                echo 'Row 1 is empty';
            }
            if($row[2] != '' && $row[3] == '' && $row[4] == ''){
                echo 'Row 2 and 3 are empty';
            }
            if($row[2] != '' && $row[3] != '' && $row[4] == ''){
                echo 'Row 3 is empty';
            }
            if($row[2] != '' && $row[3] != '' && $row[4] != ''){
                echo 'Every row is set';
            }
```

Comment: Do you want specific error messages or all-or-nothing?

Comment: Well for educational purposes I want both hehe.

Comment: When I said 'error messages', I actually meant the `echo`s that you're using. Because if you want to see all the scenarios, then your current code is as good as it gets. Else you could just use `empty()` for all rows in 1 `if` statement.

Comment: How is your data organized?

Comment: Use a loop (from 2 - 4 in this case) to add the empty ones to an array and after the loop, distinguish 4 situations: 0 empty, 1 empty, all empty or 2 - (n-1) empty. That way you can generate the exact same error messages you have now.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
    $empty = [];
    foreach ($row as $i => $val) {
        if (!$val) {
            $empty[] = $i;
        }
    }
    if ($empty) {
        $msg = 'Row ' . implode(' and ', $empty) . ' are (is) empty';
    } else {
        $msg = 'Every row is set';
    }
    echo $msg;
```

Answer (score 1):

this should work for row of any length

```
function checkRow($row)
{
    $st = "";
    foreach($row as $key => $col)
    {
        if($col == '')
        {
            if($st) 
                $st .= " and ";
            $st .= "Column $key is empty ";
        }
    }
    if(!$st)
        $st = 'Every col is set';
    return $st;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Since you question seems to be academic in nature:

There are 2 different variants of answers depending on what you want to achieve.

1. Do something only on a specific combination of empty columns
2. Do something specific for every column it it is empty

Your example looks like variant 2, as you are simply printing that that specific column is empty. In this case you could write it like

```
if($row[2] == ''){
   echo 'Row 2 is empty'
}
if($row[3] == ''){
   echo 'Row 3 is empty'
}
```

Variant 1 however means that you only want to do something, when say only columns 2 and 3 are empty and the others are not.
In that case your only chance is to do it the way you have done. To make the code look cleaner you should write a function like:

```
//pseudo code:
function boolean isEmpty($column){
   if($column == ''){
      return true;
   } else {
      return false;
   }
}
```

and call it in your IFs.